# OpenCV 2.1 to OpenCV2.4 performance increase?

Tags: opencv

I was wondering if there are any performance increases when changing from OpenCV2.1 to OpenCV2.4?

Also, I've read a little about GPU development with OpenCV. Can someone recommend any beginner guides/primers? Is it as simple as redifining the matrix as cv::gpu::GpuMat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a set of performance tests in the full source build - but generally each release of openCV tries to improve performance where possible

Yes using the GPU is essentially as straight forward as use cv::gpu::Mat although not all code is ported to CUDA and of course not all code will benefit, see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/gpu.html

Comment: Is there no better documentation for the GPU programming? I've never done any CUDA work or used OpenCV much unfortunately. Nonetheless, thanks for the link ...

Comment: Other than putting ::gpu:: there isn't much to do, look at the gpu samples. It's also very easy to write your own CUDA code to add new functions - but you need to know CUDA